# cannot show the text inside input text form with html and bootstrap

Tags: html, css, input

i have this code:

```
<div class="container">
                                                        <div class="row">
                                                            <div class="col-lg-2">
                                                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                                        <button type="button"
                                                class="quantity-left-minus changeQuantity  btn btn-primary btn-number"
                                                data-type="minus">
                                          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
                                        </button>
                                    </span>
                                                                    <input type="text" id="quantity"
                                                                           class="form-control align-items-center qty-input"
                                                                           value="{{ item.product_quantity }}">
                                                                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                                        <button type="button"
                                                class="changeQuantity quantity-right-plus btn btn-primary btn-number"
                                                data-type="plus">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                                        </button>
                                    </span>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
```

it is showing like this, I want to see the text inside it, without (form-control) I can see the text, but with it, it appears like this:
[image]

Comment: Hello, it is too small and probably has some padding applied, so you just see the 'padding'

Comment: there is no padding ?

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle so I can evaluate the code and help you out. `form-control` by default includes padding.